# Typescript type checking - Backbone.Model instance cannot be type checked

Tags: backbone.js, typescript, backbone.js-collections

I'm having a problem with Typescript and Backbone collections. Here's some groundwork:

```
class BaseChartModel extends Backbone.Model { }
class ScatterPlotModel extends BaseChartModel { }
class BarChartModel extends BaseChartModel { }

class MixedChartCollection extends Backbone.Collection { public model: BaseChartModel; ... }
class ScatterPlotCollection extends Backbone.Collection { public model: ScatterPlotModel; ... }
class BarChartCollection extends Backbone.Collection { public model: BarChartModel; ... }
```

Then I do the following:

```
 var scatterPlotCollection = new ScatterPlotCollection();
 var scatterPlotCollectionXhr = scatterPlotCollection.fetch({...});

 var barChartCollection = new BarChartCollection();
 var barChartCollectionXhr = barChartCollection.fetch({...});

 $.when(scatterPlotCollectionXhr, barChartCollectionXhr).done(() => {

       mixedCollection = new MixedChartCollection();
       mixedCollection.add(scatterPlotCollection.models, { silent: true });
       mixedCollection.add(barChartCollection.models, { silent: true });
       chartViewList = new MixedChartViewList({ collection: mixedCollection });

       chartViewList.render();

 });
```

Inside render():

```
public render(){
     var self = this;
     this.$el.html(this.template({}));

     this.collection.forEach(
    (chartModel: BaseChartModel) => {
            this.$el.append(self.AddChartView(chartModel).render());                  
    }
 );

     return this;
}

public AddChartView(baseChartModel: BaseChartModel) : BaseChartView {

      var newChartView: BaseChartView;

      if(baseChartModel instanceof ScatterPlotModel){
           newChartView = new ScatterPlotView({ model: baseChartModel});
      } else if (baseChartModel instanceof BarChartModel){
           newChartView = new BarChartView({ model: baseChartModel});
      } 
      ....       
}
```

Except `instanceof` never evaluates to true because it seems that the 'class type' deriving from `Backbone.Model` gets assigned to `Backbone.Model.attributes` rather than being an instance of the class itself. I believe this is because when implementing my classes that derive from Backbone.Model I followed [this](http://blorkfish.wordpress.com/2013/03/20/typescript-strongly-typed-backbone-models/) approach and it seems like it may be the reason for this problem. Basically it delegates get/set properties on the TS class to the underlying Backbone.model.get()/set() which in turn sets the values on the `attributes` property.

It seems I have to either drop this approach (and hope that was the problem) or figure out a way to do a loosely coupled type check similar to or using `instanceof` between the `baseChartModel.attributes` object and my class prototype for `App.BackBone.Models.ScatterPlotModel`

This breakpoint is at the line with `instanceof` comparison
[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The approach that you are using seems valid enough.  I have plugged the following code into the TypeScript playground just to check a few javascript symantics:

```
class A { }

class B extends A { }

class Checker {
    static isA(input: A) {
        return (input instanceof A);
    }
}

var a = new A();
var b = new B();

document.writeln('a instanceof A ' + (a instanceof A) + '<br/>');
document.writeln('b instanceof B ' + (b instanceof B) + '<br/>');
document.writeln('b instanceof A ' + (b instanceof A) + '<br/>');
document.writeln('b instanceof A (via function) ' + Checker.isA(b) + '<br/>');

var aArray : A[] = [];

aArray.push(a);
aArray.push(b);

for(var i = 0; i < aArray.length; i++) {
    document.writeln('aArray[' + i + '] instance of A ' + (aArray[i] instanceof A) + '<br/>' );
}
```

This gives the following output:

```
a instanceof A true 
 b instanceof B true 
 b instanceof A true 
 b instanceof A checker true 
 aArray[0] instance of A true 
 aArray[1] instance of A true
```

This must mean that the call

```
mixedCollection.add( scatterPlotCollection.models, { silent: true });
```

is causing the problem here.
Possibly scatterPlotCollection.models is NOT returning your original objects ( i.e. ScatterPlotModel or BarChartModel ), and is instead just returning [Object object], hence the instance of is failing ?

Hope this helps,

Comment: Thank you for taking a go at this although it's not quite a solution. I realize the full scope of this problem now so I posted a separate question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15775092/typescript-with-typelite-run-time-type-checking) for a more general solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

I guess I know where  a 'bug': somehow declaration

```
public model: CustomModelType
```

doesn't work;

But, if you will create a collection like this:

```
 new MyCustomCollection(null, { model: CustomModelType });
```

Then backbone will be able to create a models as expected.

Why it happens, I don't know :( 
May be a bug in type definition.